# procedure created with compilation errors - `endif`

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax-error

```
create or replace procedure checkIdd(u varchar2,p varchar2,st out varchar2)
is  
begin   
select  wmode into st from tblLogin where userid = u and pass = p;
if st='ADMIN' then
 st:='ADMIN';
else
select wmode into st from tbl_user where name=u and pass=p;
 if st='user' then
   st:='user';
 else        
   st:='No account exists';
 endif;
end if;
commit; 
exception
when no_data_found then
     st:='null';
end;
/
```

The parameter `u` is the user id, `p` is the user's password. I have to check whether wmode is admin then check if id exists in tbllogin else if wmode is user then check from tbl_user.

I got a compilation error but I'm not going to tell you what it is.

Comment: -1 for "*correct this asap*". This is not a free coding service.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp I assume you won't tell us what you fixed for a_horse :-)

Comment: you can see the original version of the Q if you want, hopefully it'll be clear :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace `endif` with `end if`, there is no `endif` keyword in PL/SQL

```
     else        
       st:='No account exists';
     endif; <======================================  END <space> IF 
   end if
```